# Microsoft list app issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

I have a question has anyone tried using Microsoft list app in teams for guest users? It works for android from mobile, doesn’t work in iOS , works in web, doesn’t work on desktop

Comment: Do these guest users have a SharePoint & OneDrive license assigned to them?

Comment: Just reproduced the same behavior in Microsoft Teams client using a guest user account. But I cannot get it to work in browser as well, it opens blank when being clicked on the Lists tab. I would suggest you submit feedback via the Help button on Teams client application or the UserVoice forum: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/